# MATLAB: Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a new text file called Table. I keep getting this error:

> Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

My code is:

```
fileID = fopen('Table.txt', 'a+');
fprintf(fileID, '%6d %12d\r\n', 'Prior', 'New');
fprintf(fileID, '%6d %12d\r\n', A);
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: Is your current directory in MATLAB writable?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm pretty new to MATLAB.

Comment: Try creating this file using some other means outside MATLAB in the same directory, for example using a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by changing the path to a temporary directory using `cd(tempdir)`.